# Missing icons for Trusted Microsoft Store Apps in Start Menu search and taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu

Help!

The icons for my *Trusted Microsoft Store apps* are missing from my start menu when I search for them. They are also missing from my tasbar. I alo notice that icons are missing for files that are associated with these apps are missing.

Any idea on how to solve this?

### When Using Search

Searching in the start menu won't show the icon for Trusted Microsoft Store apps. Other app icons are visible in the search.
[image: Slack icon missing]
[image: Setings icon missing]
[image: Calculator icon missing, other icons showing]

### In start menu

The icons for the store apps are visible in the menu when not searching:
[image: Not missing when not searching]

### Not visible in taskbar either

Here you can see that both the Slack and Store app icons aren't visible on the taskbar:
[image: Slack Icon missing on taskbar]

### No file icons for associated apps

My images are associated with Windows Photos (also a Microsoft Trusted Store App). The aren't showing their icons.
[image: PNG icons not visible]

### What I've done so far

I've been searching Google and the MS fora for hours now. What I've tried so far:

- Running all Windows Updates
- Upgrading to [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/10/17/get-windows-10-fall-creators-update/)
- Clearing the general icon cache by deleting `C:\Users\[snip]\AppData\Local\IconCache.db`
- Clearing Explorer icon cache by deleting `C:\Users\[snip]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\IconCache*.db`
- Re-reregistring all Windows store apps with PowerShell by running: `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`
- Running Disk Clean Up and choosing Clean Up System Files
- Running WSReset.exe

All to no avail. I hope you guys know a solution.

Comment: I have the exact same thing, its happening on a domain account so the only answer here isn't viable for me.

Comment: @Nate Try this: https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing

Comment: I have the same problem. The easiest "fix" is to create a new account.

Comment: If you are facing the issue for Google Drive File Stream then, I've already posted a fix here: https://superuser.com/a/1441161/250676

Comment: One discovery I've made is that when adding a never-installed app from the store, I get the icons in search, but if I uninstall, then reinstall a 'corrupt' app the icons still don't appear

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know why this worked, I read it somewhere (I forget the exact source) but someone suggested removing the Google Drive File Stream application. I got fed up with this issue, and tried it on a whim not expecting much, and it actually fixed the situation and the icons came back *during* the installation.

Comment: Yep... works! Amazing...

Comment: Its not ideal, but it seems to fix the issue. Go figure, whatever that app is doing is causing some problems.

Comment: This may be your source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/blank-icon-on-taskbar-windows-10/02340804-650b-43b6-b5e6-b4f20c497dfa
No solution still for us who don't have Google Drive File Stream.

Comment: This worked for me too. My mind is blown. Well done Google for breaking something

Comment: Worked for me too - but why?

Comment: @ManuelMartinez I don't know why or how. If I did, I'd share here. If anyone has insight please share I'd love to learn more and I'd update the post to include it.

Comment: same here, once Google Drive File Stream was uninstalled all icons reappeared miraculously. WTF Google ....`? Thanks a lot for the tip @Nate

Comment: this is nuts... I basically tried every advice (except re-installation) and nothing worked. The interessting thing is, it only was one account on the PC. The other account did not had the issue at all. I did not try Google Drive, because it was not installed. HOWEVER: I installed Google Drive with FileStream now (https://dl.google.com/drive-file-stream/GoogleDriveFSSetup.exe it had to be that one - the normal drive would not work, even the installers are equal in size) - and what do you know, the icons re-appeared. It looks like that something in the installer refreshes the icons.

Comment: Interesstingly, the google drive installation/deinstallation fixed it for most of the apps but for example the Windows Store itself still is missing...

Comment: This worked for me as well! Also deleted Dropbox just in case. The bug was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive File Stream was/is the culprit for me. Uninstalling this app brings the icons back. I don't have the option of removing the app so I live with this fix until I get Windows reinstalled and the dice gets rolled to see if the problem comes back.

What can temporarily work (day by day) is by removing the following Registry Key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png\shellex\{E357FCCD-A995-4576-B01F-234630154E96}
```

And then restarting Windows Explorer from the Task Manager.

This registry key will come back so when your icons disappear again you will need to do this again. This works for all of the icons except the Windows Mail icon.

I tried all of the fixes on this site and a bunch of others short of reinstalling Windows. Nothing had any effect. I think a large percentage of people have this problem because of Google Drive File Stream. Google seems uninterested in solving this problem as it doesn't affect everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some troubleshooting steps in ascending order of severity.
Before starting, take careful backups including a system image.
I suggest using for that
[AOMEI Backupper Standard Free](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).
Create also the AOMEI boot CD or USB and test that it can boot and can see
both your system disk and the disk where the image backup is stored.

To reinstall all Store apps for the current account :

1. Open Windows PowerShell as Administrator
2. Copy and paste the command below in PowerShell, and press Enter

   ```
   Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
   ```
3. Wait for this to finish and reboot.

If this does not work, Windows is in bad shape.
Start by checking the integrity of system files :

1. Open an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) or an elevated Windows PowerShell.
2. In the elevated command prompt, execute the command below :

   ```
   sfc /scannow
   ```
3. Reboot

If this does not help, follow the steps outlined in the article
[How to Repair Windows 10 Image using DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html).

If the problem is still there, we start getting into the heavy stuff.
Execute
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open the Command Prompt or Run... window (whichever you like) and execute the following command:

  ```
  ie4uinit.exe -show
  ```

This solution is for Windows 10 only. It might or might not help; in case it did, credits goes to Ramesh Srinivasan. (I think he said he had a Super User account too.)

Comment: This does cause the taskbar to flash, but the icons remain missing for me.

Comment: Hmm... So, the cache itself is not the problem; probably the icon itself is corrupted.

Comment: Yeah. I have tried the other posts suggestion to reinstall apps, as well what OP has said he tried using WSReset, etc. I've noticed that by changing the task bar settings to NOT GROUP items, Icons for Centennial apps (non UWP) seem to show up; however, the UWP apps don't show up regardless and when the task bar is grouping the Centennial apps icons don't show up either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by [@Nate](https://superuser.com/a/1334084/970766) - interestingly for me it worked **after installing** Google Drive for desktop from this place: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379. I never had installed it earlier, so there was no need to uninstall it, but installing it resolved the issue magically! I then uninstalled it and the icons still show up, no problem at all :).

Also found a github page somebody created, it might be interesting for some: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379