# Ghost icons in taskbar and icons not showing in windows search

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, windows-search

All of a sudden my icons for apps in my taskbar has disappeared but the apps are still there and when I go to search for some of the apps which have a ghost icon in taskbar it shows what appears to be like paper with the top right corner folded. Most of the built in Microsoft apps do that like Microsoft store and solitaire. But in the all apps section its fine.

Broken in search image:

[image: Broken in search image]

Broken in taskbar image:

[image: Broken in taskbar image]

**EDIT:** I was searching for random answers then I found one about registry edit .png area ([Some Windows 10 UWP icons not displaying on search, or in settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1319157/some-windows-10-uwp-icons-not-displaying-on-search-or-in-settings?rq=1)) and I followed the first answer and now all app images are fixed as long as they are in the taskbar. But .png icons in the file explorer still show the paper icon for some reason and apps still show weird paper icon in search.

Comment: Try DISM / SFC as an initial repair.  Things get more complicated after that.  .....    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Your icon cache is corrupted brotendo. Follow the instructions over at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10

Comment: @Gantendo That didn't work at all

Comment: @Bentheminernz That sucks for you. Then the problem is bigger than just the icon cache. Follow John's advice.

Comment: @Gantendo Ok will try. But all the icons appear on my brothers account and the admin account so I have no clue whats wrong for me....

Comment: Maybe you can just create a new user account and use that.

Comment: @Gantendo Problem is that all my stuff will be left behind on this account or is there a easy way to copy across things

Comment: Files are easy to copy. Installed programs and their settings not so much :-(

Comment: @John Even your solution didn't work. I have no clue what to do now.

Comment: I suggest backing up your data and reinstalling Windows at this point.

Comment: @John tbh I can live with it. I can't be bothered to backup and reinstall windows. It must be an account settings problem or something so I'll keep searching.

Comment: @Gantendo I then found out that even files like .mp4 and .mp3 have the same weird paper icon like the guy in this post (Yes I did try all those answers but none worked) https://superuser.com/questions/1261293/missing-icons-for-trusted-microsoft-store-apps-in-start-menu-search-and-taskbar?rq=1